Members of the Vestenmannavnjar / Vendel Pantheon
The description of the Vestenmannavnjar / Vendel lists the all-father and two sons as major deities of the pantheon. Is there more information on this pantheon? Is it different from the real-life Norse pantheon, and if yes, who are the members and what is known about them?

There are no further details in second edition
In the second edition there is nothing that I have found about any specific gods of the Vesten beyond the Allfather. There are only snippets of lore and tradition that refer to them as just “gods”. Even Nations of Theah, Volume 1, which has details about the Vendel/Vesten Nation, and Cities of Faith and Wonder, which details the city of Neiuwehoop on the Western coast, have little to say about the old gods. (The latter focuses on the the conflict between Reformed Objectionism, or Winterism - the Thean equivalent of Calvinism - and the Vaticine Church.)
This is in keeping with a seeming desire to keep divine matters more ambiguous in the second edition. Religious figures can and do work miracles, but this is generally not for player characters, who can only “work miracles” in the metaphorical sense. They cannot have a concrete link to the divine.
First edition had a different take
The first edition book Nations of Théah: Vendel • Vesten opens with the saga The Grumfather Cycle which introduces “Grumfather, the Grey Wanderer”, a clear analogue for Odin.
The saga (and subsequent summary) describes Grumfather as the creator and only god until the coming of a Great Wyrm from “beyond the sky”. With Grumfather’s advice, “the twenty-five” - the jarls of the original Vesten tribes - unite to defeat the Wyrm in battle, using its scales to unlock magical powers. Those scales are the origin of the magical runes, and the twenty-five became the first living runes, making them divine. They are worshipped as gods alongside Grumfather, and considered separate to the ancestors who are also venerated. Each rune is thus named for the jarl who embodied it, and so rune magic and the gods are directly linked.
Note that it was possible for a Vesten sorcerer character to embody a single rune themselves, permanently, though this didn’t grant them divinity.
The two might be compatible, but with a bit of work
Second edition doesn’t explicitly contradict the first edition story: the otherwise unnamed “Allfather” is still the creator god, though there are hints that the other gods were somehow involved in creation as well. These other unnamed gods are said to be  his “family”, with just one more specific reference to him having two sons - “one a trickster and the other a not-too-bright warrior” (clearly suggesting Loki and Thor-like figures). With a bit of tweaking, this family could be made to fit the twenty-five, with the same names and similar history if you want to use them (though no single rune-god from first edition is an exact fit for Loki or Thor).
The old rune sorcery of Lærdom has been removed (perhaps because it was too closely modelled on real world Icelandic Futhark), along with the legend that supported it. It is replaced in Nations of Théah Vol. 1 by Galdr, a new version of “lost” rune magic which features a smaller set of twelve runes (plus one more lost rune). This new version of Futhark does not directly associate runes with specific gods, or even give Vesten names for each rune, which instead represent the words used by the gods to shape creation. This still doesn’t directly contradict the story of the twenty-five - Lærdom runes were also described in this way - but it would require considerable work to explain how they co-exist.
The core rules don't include Galdr, but instead have Seidr, which represents a Vesten who has studied with a skald and learned some of their ways. Seidr is not related to a sorcerous bloodline, or even explicitly described as magic, and while it can involve casting runes, it doesn’t have to. It’s left open to be interpreted as a religious or cultural practice instead, though with at least a strong hint of the supernatural. It is not explicitly connected to the gods, either, though skalds are said to keep the religion alive by telling the old sagas. So if you want to use the old mythology, you might be better off sticking with just Seidr.

"Seidr is instead available to player characters": A small bit about rune magic - isn't Galdr the 2e version of rune magic available to PCs?

@vicky_molokh-unsilenceMonica yeah, I didn’t word that very clearly - I’ll clean that up. But Seidr  isn’t described as magic in the same way as Lærdom.

@vicky_molokh-unsilenceMonica - oh, wait! Yes, I totally forgot about Galdr. Thank you, that does change my answer significantly.
